# Sql server cursor results not displayed properly?

Tags: sql-server, database-cursor

Please assist to answer this. Why does my CURSOR result, does not display the correct results? See both photos.

```
        declare @FullName varchar;
        declare @InvoiceID int;
        declare @CustomerID int;
        declare @DeliveryInstructions varchar;
        declare Salescur cursor for
        --select---
            select p.FullName, InvoiceID,CustomerID,DeliveryInstructions
            from Sales.Invoices s 
            inner join Application.People p
            on s.SalespersonPersonID = p.PersonID
            where InvoiceDate = '2016-05-31'
            and s.SalespersonPersonID = 8;

        open Salescur;
        fetch next from Salescur into @FullName,@InvoiceID,@CustomerID,
        @DeliveryInstructions;
        while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        begin 
            --print @InvoiceID + CHAR(13);
            print @FullName + 'has delivery instructions to these addresses: ' + @DeliveryInstructions
            fetch next from Salescur into @FullName,@InvoiceID,@CustomerID,
        @DeliveryInstructions;
        end
        close Salescur;
        deallocate Salescur;
    end;
```

[Cursor Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzCHO.png)

[Table selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prEqc.png)

Comment: Because using `varchar` without a length is a [bad habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) that you should kick.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, yes indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeroen has said, you have declared a variable as type `VARCHAR` but you haven't specified a field length. This will result in a length of 1.

You need to do

```
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(50)
```

by doing

```
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR
```

you are implicity doing

```
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(1)
```

which is why you are only getting the first character

Comment: Thanks guys! Answered my question!

Answer (score 1):

*Why* you are using `cursor`, you can also do that via `concat()` function

```
select concat(p.FullName, ' has delivery instructions to these addresses: ', p.DeliveryInstructions)
from Sales.Invoices s 
inner join Application.People p 
      on s.SalespersonPersonID = p.PersonID
where InvoiceDate = '2016-05-31' and 
      s.SalespersonPersonID = 8;
```

For *older* version you can use

```
select p.FullName + ' has delivery instructions to these addresses: ' +  p.DeliveryInstructions 
. . .
```

Comment: Presumably because of the use of PRINT.